# Column still added after using javax.persistence.Transient?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

So I have a hibernate model class, which is:

```
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "transaction_header")
public class TransactionHeader implements java.io.Serializable {
@Column(name = "transaction_header_id", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "serial")
    private Long transactionHeaderId;

    @Column(name = "trans_type_code")
    private String transactionTypeCode;

    @Transient
    public String stateTax;

    @Transient
    public String federalTax;

    /**then setter getter code**/
}
```

When I run it on my local database, federal Tax and state Tax column were still generated even I already used Transient on it. I need those 2 columns **to not be generated** on my database. How can I do it? Thanks